# T-SQL FOR JSON PATH but without a column name in the JSON result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, for-json

Is there a way in SQL to return an array of values without the column name included?  I've searched for a solution but have not found anything

```
CREATE TABLE #data (
    id int
);

INSERT INTO #data VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO #data VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO #data VALUES (3)
INSERT INTO #data VALUES (4)
INSERT INTO #data VALUES (5)
INSERT INTO #data VALUES (6)
INSERT INTO #data VALUES (7)
INSERT INTO #data VALUES (8)
INSERT INTO #data VALUES (9)
INSERT INTO #data VALUES (10)

SELECT id FROM #data FOR JSON PATH

DROP TABLE #data
```

The above T-SQL returns the below JSON but I want it without the column name just an array of values

```
[
    {
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 4
    },
    {
        "id": 5
    },
    {
        "id": 6
    },
    {
        "id": 7
    },
    {
        "id": 8
    },
    {
        "id": 9
    },
    {
        "id": 10
    }
]
```

I would like the resulting output to be:

```
[
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10
]
```

Comment: That's a JSON array. If that's all you want, you'd likely be better off using string aggregation and concatenating the brackets (`[]`) to either end

Comment: This is part of a much larger bit of SQL for a much larger json file

Comment: You might want to give a bit more of a realistic representation of your goals then.

Comment: Not really possible to give an example of a 189 line SQL statement that returns data in JSON format from a dozen tables.  The only part was what is above I wanted it formatted as a simple JSON Array so it didn't have the column name instead of an array of objects.

Comment: I said realistic representation, not your entire data set. For the above the answer is simply `SELECT CONCAT('[',STRING_AGG(id,','),']') FROM #data;` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2d760d9387d2e42c271670824a4b9527)